# PHP Regex doesn't match

Tags: php, regex, steam

I need to see if input contains steam id. I tried to see if my preg_match is valid.

```
$regex = "/^STEAM_0:[01]:[0-9]{7,8}$/";
if(preg_match($regex, 'STEAM_0:1:38401525'))
{ 
echo 'OK'; } else {echo 'ERROR';}
```

I tried it in online tool
https://regex101.com/r/nI0kQ7/1

What's wrong? Why it always gives me an "ERROR" ?

Comment: [It works](http://ideone.com/uPoQjy), but depending on PHP version, you might need to add `$matches`. Try using `if(preg_match($regex, 'STEAM_0:1:38401525', $matches))`. See http://ideone.com/k492KV

Comment: `$regex = "/^STEAM_0:[01]:[0-9]{7,8}$/";
preg_match($regex, 'STEAM_1:1:38399475', $matches);
if($matches)
    {  echo 'OK'; }else {echo 'ERROR';}`

It is still ERROR

Comment: Try using it as in my second demo. Or check if you really have the same values here and on your system.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and it's working fine, here is code snippet

```
$regex = "/^STEAM_0:[01]:[0-9]{7,8}$/";
if(preg_match($regex, 'STEAM_0:1:38401525', $match))
{ 
    echo 'OK'.PHP_EOL; 
    print_r($match); 
} else {
    echo 'ERROR';
}
```

and this produces the output like

```
OK
Array
(
    [0] => STEAM_0:1:38401525
)
```

Check out this [`Demo`](http://ideone.com/eUu61o) where code is in action

and **[here](http://www.regexr.com/3c49q)** is **regexr** in action for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good I was test on php version 5.2 [here](http://phptester.net/) and give me OK, check your php compiler or maiby your entired code.

I can't save my code from there but add your question code for verify:

```
$regex = "/^STEAM_0:[01]:[0-9]{7,8}$/";
if(preg_match($regex, 'STEAM_0:1:38401525'))
{ 
echo 'OK'; } else {echo 'ERROR';}
```

Comment: The link is to an empty tester.  Please post your code in your answer and if you want to include the link, make sure it is valid.

Comment: add your code from your question `$regex = "/^STEAM_0:[01]:[0-9]{7,8}$/";
if(preg_match($regex, 'STEAM_0:1:38401525'))
{ 
echo 'OK'; } else {echo 'ERROR';}` => 'OK'